# Additional context for tomcat:run goal

Tags: maven-2, tomcat, pom.xml

How do I add an additional directory based context to a tomcat:run configuration?

I have the following jetty plugin configuration:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <contextHandlers>
          <contextHandler implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler">
            <contextPath>/media/data</contextPath>
            <resourceBase>/somedir/media/data</resourceBase>
            <handler implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ResourceHandler" />
          </contextHandler>
        </contextHandlers>
        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        <webAppSourceDirectory>foo-project/target/foo-webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
...
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
...
</build>
```

How do I do this with tomcat:run?

I have a context.xml file in the tomcatconf dir

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context path="/media" docBase="/somedir/media"/>
```

but this seems to get ignored.
I've also tried to explicitly set the contextFile parameter in the plugin configuration, but to no avail.

Reference:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

Comment: Show what you tried with the tomcat plugin. And please describe what didn't work more precisely.

Comment: I have a directory on my computer called /somedir/media.  I want the maven tomcat plugin goal tomcat:run to serve the files and subirectories of /somedir/media at http://localhost:8080/media  I know how to do this with the jetty:run goal.  How do I accomplish this with the tomcat:run goal?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [deployment description](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deployment.html) of the tomcat plugin.

Place the context.xml file to the default location

```
src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml
```

or use tomcat:run with a contextFile property on the commandline

```
mvn tomcat:run -DcontextFile="<path-to-your-context.xml-file>"
```